# QuickBlox 2.0 Chat dialog - how to detect an user join or leave group chat dialog?

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I have trouble with QuickBlox when update from version 1.2.4 to version 2.0.

In version 2.0 how to detect a user join or leave group chat dialog?

In version 1.2.4 i use ParticipantListener but version 2.2 QBGroupChat cant not add this listener ?

Thank in advance.

Version 1.2.4:

```
PacketListener participantListener = new PacketListener() {

    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        Presence presence = (Presence) packet;

        if (presence.getType() == Presence.Type.available) {
            // user entered the room

        } else if (presence.getType() == Presence.Type.unavailable) {
            // user left the room

        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to use QBParticipantListener for version 2.1:

```
private QBParticipantListener participantListener;

participantListener = new QBParticipantListener() {
    @Override
    public void processPresence(QBGroupChat groupChat, QBPresence presence) {

    }
};

private QBGroupChat currentChatRoom = ...;
currentChatRoom.addParticipantListener(participantListener);
```

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Get_online_users