# Listener to be notified about Group Chat movements - Quickblox Android API 2.0

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I'm using QuickBlox API 2.0.
To be notified about Private Chat dialogs I can use:

```
    QBPrivateChatManager qBPrivateChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager();
        qBPrivateChatManager.addPrivateChatManagerListener(new QBPrivateChatManagerListener() {

            @Override
            public void chatCreated(QBPrivateChat chat, boolean arg1) {
//      handle chat message here
          }
        });
```

But QBGroupChatManager there is no similar listener. So I can't notify the user if somebody put him in a Group.

I would like a easy way (like private chat) to be notified about movements in chat group dialogs. Is it possible?

Below there is a link to a similar issue:
[QuickBlox 2.0 Chat dialog - how to detect an user join or leave group chat dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419282/quickblox-2-0-chat-dialog-how-to-detect-an-user-join-or-leave-group-chat-dialo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it should be done http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Create_new_group_chat_dialog